# Unable to paginate: Invalid total value (must be an integer > 0) In Php PDO

Tags: mysql, pdo, pagination

I am working on a query for some days and stuck to execute it successfully. I am using pagination class which is located here 
[Pagination.class](http://www.catchmyfame.com/paginator/3/paginator.class.txt)

Here is my code so far. The Problem is that it keeps showing me error

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['maker'])){$makes = $_REQUEST['maker']; }
if(isset($_REQUEST['transmission'])){ $trans = $_REQUEST['transmission']; } 
if(isset($_REQUEST['year_from'])){ $yearf = $_REQUEST['year_from']; } 
if(isset($_REQUEST['year_to'])){ $yeart = $_REQUEST['year_to']; } 
if(isset($_REQUEST['fuel'])){ $fuels = $_REQUEST['fuel']; } 


if($makes == NULL || NULL == $makes)
{
$makes='%';
 }


 if($trans == NULL || NULL == $trans)
{
 $trans='%';
 }


if($fuels == NULL || NULL == $fuels)
{
$fuels='%';
 }




 try{

$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=vc', 'root', '');
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 

 $result = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM vehicle WHERE 
(`Make` LIKE :maker) AND(`Transmission` LIKE :transmission)  AND 
(YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`Year`,"%Y")) BETWEEN (:year_from) AND (:year_to)) AND
 (`Fuel` LIKE :fuel)'); 

$result->bindParam(':maker', $makes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':transmission', $trans, PDO::PARAM_STR);
 $result->bindParam(':year_from', $yearf,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':year_to', $yeart, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':fuel', $fuels, PDO::PARAM_STR);

$result->execute(); 
  $num_rows=$result->fetchColumn();  

$pages = new Paginator($num_rows,5,array(15,3,6,9,12,25,50,100,250,'All'));
//echo $pages->display_pages();

//echo "<span class=\"\">".$pages->display_jump_menu().$pages->display_items_per_page()."</span>";



  $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM vehicle WHERE 
(`Make` LIKE :maker) AND (`Transmission` LIKE :transmission)  AND  
(YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`Year`,"%Y")) BETWEEN (:year_from) AND (:year_to)) 
AND (`Fuel` LIKE :fuel) ORDER BY Year DESC LIMIT :start,:end');

$stmt->bindParam(':start', $pages->limit_start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':end', $pages->limit_end, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':maker', $makes, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':transmission', $trans, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':year_from', $yearf, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':year_to', $yeart, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindParam(':fuel', $fuels, PDO::PARAM_STR);



$stmt->execute();
 $rs = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

**Unable to paginate: Invalid total value (must be an integer > 0)**

when leaving Year fields blank it gives the error. And when year_from and year_to fields be inserted its working fine. Could Anyone Help Please. Stuck For 5 days

Database Field For Year is **Date**

The Problem is in between clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave the `year_from` and `year_to` parameters empty, `$yearf` and `$yeart` stay undefined and the following code

```
$result->bindParam(':year_from', $yearf,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result->bindParam(':year_to', $yeart, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

will bind the parameters to empty strings, which results in a query like this

```
BETWEEN ('') AND ('')
```

The result is empty, `$num_rows` is `0`, the validation in the Pagination constructor fails.

You should develop with `error_reporting=E_ALL` and `display_errors=On` in php.ini, this would have warned you about the undefined variable.

Comment: Thats i know, that If year_from and year_to fields will empty then the error occurs, what i want to know how to fix this, if this two fields are empty , how to show all records

Comment: I have added these lines to check if fields are empty then fetch the whole row. but its not work 

if($yearf == NULL || NULL == $yearf)
{
  $yearf='%';
}


if($yeart == NULL || NULL == $yeart)
{
  $yeart='%';
}

Comment: You could set them to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 and 9999-12-31 23:59:59 if they are empty

Comment: You are saying this 

if($yearf == NULL || NULL == $yearf)
{
 
  $yearf='0000-00-00';
}

if($yeart == NULL || NULL == $yeart)
{
 
  $yeart='0000-00-00';
}

Comment: No, for yeart use the maximum value. Also I would use if(empty($yeart)) as condition.

Comment: Thanks Working Good Now.